# Hazelcast cluster not starting

Tags: hazelcast

I'm not able to see members added to the cluster when I start from multiple ports. Below is just the basic configuration. Each seems to have its own port.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class HazelcastApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HazelcastApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public HazelcastInstance createStorageNode() throws Exception {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
}



Members [1] {
        Member [169.254.137.152]:5702 this
}


Members [1] {
        Member [169.254.137.152]:5701 this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have multiple network interfaces on the machine you're running on while running multicast.  Modify your above method to:

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public HazelcastInstance createStorageNode() throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true)
                .getMembers()
                .add("127.0.0.1");
        //.add("169.254.137.152");  // or this
        Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    }
```

Comment: How so? Becuase its the same local env right? Also if u see the ports that the application started on , the ip is the same

Comment: I'm only guessing here so will need need more info.  Please run "ifconfig -a" if on mac, "ipconfig /all" if on windows, "ip a" in linux to list all the interfaces on your machine.

Comment: If you are running virtual box or vmware fusion, please refer to the following previously reported issue:  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/11415